# Why does my structure element carry padding bytes?

Tags: c, windows, memory, alignment, padding

I have a confusing behaviour with the memory alignment of structure elements. Consider these two structures:

```
typedef struct s_inner {
    unsigned long ul1;
    double        dbl1;
    fourth_struct s4;
    unsigned long ul2;
    int           i1;
} t_inner;

typedef struct s_outer {
    other_struct    member1; /* 4-byte aligned, 40 bytes in terms of sizeof() */
    unsigned long   member2;
    t_inner         member3; /* see above */
} t_outer;
```

When I inspect the memory layout of t_outer, I could see that the elements of `member1` are 4-byte aligned, just as I would expect it.
Also the memory layout of `member3` is as expected: `ul1` has 4 padding bytes attached so that `dbl1` is aligned on an 8-byte border (normal on Win32).

**However,** when I inspect the memory layout of `member2`, I could see that this member has 4 padding bytes attached to it.
Could anyone explain why on earth `member2` receives padding bytes? My expectation was that `member2` does not carry a padding.

---

**Edit 1:**
See this memory dump. Before filling the structure elements, I've `memset`'d the whole `t_outer` structure with `p`'s:

- the red area is `member1`
- the blue area is `member2`
- the green area is `member3`
- the yellow area marks the location of `dbl1` within `member3`

[image: memory-layout]

---

***Constraints***

- Compiler is VS2012
- the actual stucture of `other_struct` should not matter here, it's a 40-byte sized 4-byte aligned structure
- I do **not** want any workarounds for the behavior (reordering, packing, ...) but an explanation why this is happening.

Comment: What is "other_struct" ?

Comment: Padding is inserted at the discretion of the compiler, so which compiler are you using?

Comment: Can you clarify where the padding is? Before or after member2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so that dbl1 is aligned on an 8-byte border

Sure.  But that alignment guarantee means bupkis if the structure itself is not aligned to 8 as well.  Which is a guarantee that's *normally* provided by the compiler's address choices for the data section and the stack frame.  Or the memory allocator.  All guarantee at least alignment to 8.

But when you embed the structure inside *s_outer* then those 4 bytes of padding *before* member3 (not after member2) are required to get the alignment guarantee back.

Also note that a structure can have padding after the last member.  Which may be required to ensure that members are still aligned when the structure is stored in an array.  Same reason.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. One addon: the green area *after* the double seems no longer to be aligned. I assume that the alignment has to be kept to 8 until all doubles of the structure were read and then pop to 4. Is this correct?

Comment: No idea what you mean, looks aligned to me and I see only one double.  We can't see "fourth_struct".

Comment: "I assume that the alignment has to be kept to 8 until all doubles of the structure were read and then pop to 4. Is this correct?"  No, it is not correct.  The VS docs don't actually specify the behavior precisely in that area, but given a sequence of members of types `double`, `int`, `int`, `double`, it is consistent with the VS docs for the second `int` to be aligned on a 4-byte boundary (and that's how I predict it *would* be aligned).

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I've opened a new question on this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27858493/520162

Answer (score 2):

The VS2012 docs [describe its padding behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hx1b6kkd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  In particular, they specify that the alignment requirement for a `struct` is the largest alignment requirement of any of its members.  Member `member3`'s type `t_inner` has a member of type `double`, with an 8-byte alignment requirement, therefore `member3` overall has an 8-byte alignment requirement (and, also, `t_outer` has an 8-byte alignment requirement).  Padding is required between `member2` and `member3` to obtain 8-byte alignment of `member3`.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. The 8-byte alignment of `t_outer` and `member3` do not affect the alignment of `member1`, right?

Comment: Well, there's no *direct* implication for `member1`, but because it's the first member of `t_outer`, `t_outer` requires 8-byte alignment, and VS2012 lays out members in declaration order, `member1` will always be aligned on an 8-byte boundary.