# Why does the memory alignment change within a structure?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2012, memory, alignment

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27841898/why-does-my-structure-element-carry-padding-bytes), I [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27843030/520162) that when a structure that has 8-byte alignment gets embedded into another structure with 4-byte alignment, a padding is needed **before** the 8-byte aligned structure.

Understood.

At least I thought that I understood.

The [VS 2012 docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hx1b6kkd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) say:

> For structures, unions, and arrays, the alignment-requirement is the largest alignment-requirement of its members.

So, if I have a structure like this:

```
typedef struct s_inner {
  unsigned long ul1;
  double        dbl1;
  fourth_struct s4;
  unsigned long ul2;
  int           i1;
} t_inner;
```

I'd expect **all members of this structure would be 8-byte aligned** since the `double` is 8-byte aligned.

But my memory dump shows me this:

[image: memdump]

`t_inner` starts from address `1B8`:

- `1B8`: the `unsigned long` is padded because the structure is 8-byte aligned
- `1C0`: The `double` consumes 8 bytes
- `1C8`: `fourth_struct` follows, **it has 4-byte alignment**

Until now, everything is as expected. But now **the alignment switches inside `t_inner`**:
On address `1E8`, I'd expect to find just the `unsigned long` here, padded with 4 bytes so that the following `int` is also aligned on 8 bytes. But it seems as if the alignment has now changed since the `unsigned long` does *not* carry padding bytes. Instead, the following `int` is placed with a 4-byte alignment.

Why does the alignment switch inside `t_inner`? Which rule is applied here?

Comment: could anyone please explain the downvotes???

Comment: No clue about the down-votes. I was about to say that that sentence is trying to describe the alignment requirements of *the struct*, not its individual members. but Jasen described it already. So upticked there.

Comment: This is quite a good article about data alignment... http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/pa-dalign/ Perhaps you'll find it useful :)

Comment: "When a structure that has 8-byte alignment gets embedded into another structure with 4-byte alignment, a padding is needed before the 8-byte aligned structure".  No.  Padding may be required before the inner `struct` or it may not, depending on the alignment requirements of all the outer `struct`'s members up to and including the inner `struct`.  The alignment requirement of the outer `struct` doesn't directly factor in, nor does the fact that the outer and inner `struct`s have different alignment requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'd expect all members of this structure would be 8-byte aligned since
>   the double is 8-byte > aligned.

Well, no. Each *type* has its own alignment *inside* the struct,  and *the struct itself* has an alignment that is the *greatest* of the alignments of it's content.

```
aligned.    typedef struct s_inner {
      unsigned long ul1;        // 4-aligned
      double        dbl1;       // 8-aligned  (need 4 padding before this)
      fourth_struct s4;         // 4 aligned  size 32
      unsigned long ul2;        // 4 aligned  (no padding)
      int           i1;         // 4 aligned  (no padding)
      // no padding needed as struct is a multiple of 8 bytes
    } t_inner;
```

The struct itself has align 8 because of the double.

Comment: Upticked. A more extreme example of is pointer-type structure members on iSeries, which mandate a 16-byte alignment due to how that platform manages pointer validity management. As you can imagine, structures can quickly bloat. Any requests for reduced padding and alignment are ineffective (with good reason).